# ECDSA is not verifying my signature transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, signature, ethers.js

I am facing a problem with my NFT Marketplace contract.

I have LibOrder , LibOrderValidator and Marketplace contracts.

When I want to create an order, I need to get a signature and I get a WrongSignature error because the wrong address is returned from the verify function on libOrder. Can you help me ?

How can I get the correct signature value?

**modifier**

```
        Order memory order,
        bytes memory signature
    ) internal view {
        if (order.end < block.timestamp) {
            revert OrderExpired();
        }
        if (order.issuer != verify(order, signature)) {
            revert WrongSignature();
        }
        if (orderStatus[signature] != OrderStatus.NOT_PROCESSED) {
            revert AlreadyProcessed();
        }
        if (!paymentTokens[order.paymentToken]) {
            revert InvalidPaymentToken();
        }
    }
```

**LibOrder**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

enum OrderStatus {
    NOT_PROCESSED,
    FILLED,
    CANCELED
}

enum OrderKind {
    BID,
    LIST
}

enum TokenKind {
    ERC721,
    ERC1155
}

struct Order {
    address issuer;
    address nftAddress;
    address paymentToken;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint256 end;
    OrderKind kind;
    TokenKind tokenKind;
    uint256 globalBidAmount;
    PrivilegedInformation privileges;
}

struct PrivilegedInformation {
    address privilegedCollection;
    uint256 privilegedTokenId;
}

library LibOrder {
    bytes32 public constant PrivilegedInformation_TYPEHASH =
        keccak256(
            "PrivilegedInformation(address privilegedCollection,uint256 privilegedTokenId)"
        );
    bytes32 constant ORDER_TYPEHASH =
        keccak256(
            "Order(address issuer,address nftAddress,address paymentToken,uint256 price,uint256 tokenId,uint256 end,uint256 kind,uint256 tokenKind,uint256 globalBidAmount,PrivilegedInformation privileges)PrivilegedInformation(address privilegedCollection,uint256 privilegedTokenId)"
        );

    function hash(Order memory order) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encode(
                    ORDER_TYPEHASH,
                    order.issuer,
                    order.nftAddress,
                    order.paymentToken,
                    order.price,
                    order.tokenId,
                    order.end,
                    order.kind,
                    order.tokenKind,
                    order.globalBidAmount,
                    keccak256(
                        abi.encode(
                            PrivilegedInformation_TYPEHASH,
                            order.privileges.privilegedCollection,
                            order.privileges.privilegedTokenId
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

**LibOrderValidator**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/cryptography/EIP712Upgradeable.sol";

import { Order, LibOrder } from "./LibOrder.sol";

contract OrderValidator is EIP712Upgradeable {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    function verify(Order memory order, bytes memory _signature)
        public
        view
        returns (address)
    {
        return
            ECDSA
                .toTypedDataHash(_domainSeparatorV4(), LibOrder.hash(order))
                .recover(_signature);
    }
}
```

**Signature.js**

````
  const { data: walletClient } = useWalletClient();
  const { address } = useAccount();

  const [BNBAmount, setBNBAmount] = useState("");
  const [expiration, setExpiration] = useState(1);
  const collectionInfo: string = "ERC721";
  const isPrivileged = false;


 
  const  orderToSign = {
    issuer: "0x33905203045DFA61C62451fe9516F4654a6517CB",
    nftAddress: "0x412C73EBF6a0d963Eb173E85798684cfa9b38A0A",
    paymentToken: "0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd",
    price: "1000000000000000",
    tokenId: 52,
    end: Math.floor((Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) / 1000),
    kind: 1,
    tokenKind: 0,
    globalBidAmount: 0,
    privileges: {
      privilegedCollection: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      privilegedTokenId: "0",
    },
  };
 
    console.log(orderToSign);
    

  // nft contract
  const {
    config,
    error: prepareError,
    isError: isPrepareError,
  } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: "0x412C73EBF6a0d963Eb173E85798684cfa9b38A0A",
    abi: NftAbi,
    functionName: "isApprovedForAll",
    args: [address, "0x8CBF49A70272923f42195525A8d6386fB35FB340"], // user and marketplkace address
    onSuccess: (txHash) => {
      console.log(txHash);
    },
    enabled: Boolean(address),
    account: address,
  });
  const { write } = useContractWrite(config);

  const handleSignOrder = async () => {
    

    if (typeof (window as any).ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('Ethereum provider detected.');
    } else {
      console.log('Ethereum provider not detected.');
    }
    
    await (window as any).ethereum.enable();

    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((window as any).ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    console.log("signer" , signer);
    
    console.log(signer);
    const address = await signer.getAddress();
    console.log("address" , address);


    const typedData = {
      types: types, // Bu zaten tüm tip tanımlamalarını içeriyor
      domain: dynamicDomain(97),
      primaryType: 'Order',
      message: orderToSign
    };

    const signature = await signer._signTypedData(
      typedData.domain,
      typedData.types, // Burada tüm tipleri gönderiyoruz
      typedData.message
    );
    
    return signature ;

    
  };



  const handleSellItem = async () => {
    const signature = await handleSignOrder();
    console.log("Signed data:", signature);

    // approve Item
    write?.();    

    // send db and success
    try {
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="bnb amount"
          onChange={(e) => setBNBAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Expiration"
          onChange={(e) => setExpiration(Number(e.target.value))}
        />
        <button onClick={() => handleSellItem()}>Sell Item</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};```


Even though I tried the order structure and all the other solutions, I could not find the solution.
````